# How to model risk with presence-only data?

Tags: regression, random-forest, binary-data, spatial

I'm working on a dataset of bird electrocutions. There are 300 instances of electrocuted birds and I have a range of environmental data that I want to input as my predictor variables. The aim is to see which of these, if any, is useful at explaining whether a bird gets killed.

Because this is presence-only data my idea was to sample within the same region to generate an equal sized data set of pseudo-absences and then apply a binary logistic regression model.

I was wondering if this generation of absences makes sense for my proposed model or if there are alternative frameworks I would be better off pursuing (random forest?).

Thanks